# Adding data into MySQL from a dynamic jQuery form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i'm trying to insert data to MySQL from a dynamic form with jQuery. For the record, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.  **I actually achieved insert "rows" but with no data.** The best help I found right now is this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063713/adding-rows-to-mysql-from-dynamic-jquery-form-fields) for the insert to MySQL and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/uYTcW/) to jQuery script.

Thanks in advance for taking time for this.

**File: add.php**

```
<form  action="../reglas/insert.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="container">
<div id="content">
<div class="row">

<a class="add_line btn btn-small" href="#" style="margin-left:5px">+</a>
</div>

<br>
</div>



</div>

 </div>
 </div>

 <div style="margin:20px auto; width:80px;">

 <input  class="btn btn-success"  type="submit" value="Guardar">
</div>

</form>


<script>
$("#content").delegate(".add_line", "click", function() {
var content = '<div class="row">' +

                     '<div class="span3"><div class="input-append"><input type="text"   class="span2 text-right" placeholder="0.00"  id="enganche"  name="enganche" value="" /><span class="add-on">%</span></div></div>' +
                     '<div class="span3"><div class="input-append"><input type="text" class="span2 text-right" placeholder="0.00" id="comision" name="comision" value="" /><span class="add-on">%</span></div></div>' +
                     '<div class="span3"><div class="input-append"><input type="text" class="span2 text-right" placeholder="0.00" id="r1" name="r1[]" value="" /><span class="add-on">%</span></div></div>' +

                     '<div class="span2"><div class="input-append"><input type="text" class="span1 text-right" placeholder="0.00" id="r2" name="r2[]" value="" /><span class="add-on">%</span></div></div>'+

                     '<a class="del_line btn btn-small" href="#" style="margin-left:5px">-</a>&nbsp;' +
                     '<br><br>'+

                     '</div>';
$("#content").append(content);
return false;   
});

$("#content").delegate(".del_line", "click", function() {
$(this).parent().remove();
return false;  
});
</script>
```

**File: insert.php**

The Connection:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name");
mysqli_autocommit($con, false);

$flag=true;
```

The query:

```
$query="
INSERT INTO $tbl_name(
the_input,
)
VALUES (
'$the_input',
)";
```

The "for":

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['the_input']); $i++) {
$the_input = $_POST['the_input'][$i];


$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (!$result) {
$flag = false;
echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($con). ". ";
}
}
if ($flag) {
mysqli_commit($con);
echo "Done!";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @leemo, can you be more specific? I really appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: I'll take a guess at which bits of data you're trying to send and try and mock up an answer for you

Comment: thanks @leemo. This is how the actual form looks in the browser. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/61hxtuls9kwa959/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-27%20at%208.19.37%20PM.png)

Comment: can you post the entire HTML of the form? you have this all enclosed in a FORM tag right?

Comment: also, any particular reason you are using mysql commits?

Comment: @leemo I used mysql commits because I try to manage this like a "transaction", but I'm not sure that I need to use it. Also I will work in this project with "transactions", so I choose that way to learn a little more about it.

Comment: @leemo I edited the question with the HTML form, just with the section affected, because the other section is large and work without any problem, the other section put info to another Table inside the same database, but is static, without any charm.

Comment: re: commits - cool that the best way to learn. MY answer doesnt use transactions (unless I am expecting significant overhead I dont use them)

Answer (score 0):

Okey dokey.

First things first:

`$.delegate()` is deprecated so unless you are using a version that is < jQuery 1.7 (which is many versions ago) you should migrate to [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event binder/delegator function. This will ensure that your code is future proof (at least until they change the api again!)

Secondly:

I am assuming you have wrapped your data in a form tag and the values are actually getting send to the recieving page here is how I would do it:

```
if(isset($_POST['the_input']))
{
    //create connection object;
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db_name);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `the_input` VALUES (";

    //construct the query. Get the the_input data and paramater string (required for stmt binding)
    foreach($_POST['the_input'] as $value)
    {
        $query .= $value . ",";
    }

    //remove trailing comma
    $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-1);
    $query .= ")";

    //this is just so you can see what the loop did and test the output of the query, remove this when you're confident
    echo "The constructed query string is: " . $query

    if($mysqli->query($query) == false)
    {
        trigger_error($mysqli->error);
    } else {
        echo "Success! Check the DB!";
    }

} else {
    Echo "No POST data was recieved";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @leemo for the advise and the answer. let's try it!

Comment: @HcH there was an error in my code that I have now corrected... a missing bracket.

Comment: Thanks @leemo I have this error. I'm using Adobe Dw. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgp5ukcw4ihom8o/Screenshot%202013-11-27%2021.01.42.png

Comment: maybe dreamweave doesnt like that syntax... did you try running it on the server? I have updated my answer to provide and alternative

Comment: yeah,i have this...     
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/07/11731907/html/reglas/insert.php on line 32

Comment: And this is the file with the form, most of it is between <!-- -->

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xodirv63ks3xvz/add_reglas.php

Comment: Hi @leemo , I just deleted the "echo" code to avoid get the error in line 34, but now I have this one:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/07/11731907/html/reglas/insert.php on line 22

Comment: can you try this for me? in `insert.php` can you delete everything and just enter: print_r($_POST); and send me to output

Comment: this is it with the input form fields blank. `Array ( [the_input] => [comision] => [r1] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) [r2] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) )`

Comment: ok so, I think teaching you how to do this is beyond the scope of this question but: the 'invalid argument supplied for foreach' is occuring because there are no values submitted. You need to use javascript validation BEFORE the form is submitted in order to ensure that there are values in each input and then loop over the submitted values with the foreach (any input that has the attribute name="the_input" will then be passed to the $_POST['the_input'] array and you can loop over it. and add them to the DB)

Comment: i'm trying not to be really dummy here... but i tried again with some values(inside inputs) and get the same answer. But I don't try to take a lot of time from you. Thanks a lot leemo.